# How to disable iOS Link Preview with javascript css or html attr

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-chrome, dom

When you hold on a link *in Chrome / Safari with iOS*, it displays an annoying **link preview**, problems comes when i have like a sortable `<ul>` list items ( with full link inside it )
So if you hold you drag ( drag event present on my `<li>` if you click/tap you go to the link `<a>`.

**iOS problem:**  When i hold just when it should start the drag event, this annoying system modal appears, blocking all the drag process and destroying the UX.

I have tried preventing default actions, pointer events none the link inside the element when the drag start, but nothing, keeps appearing

```
element.sortable.on('drag:start', (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
```

any ideas how to fix this with (js,css or some html attr ?) thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: hi, did you manage to solve it? I'm searching the web for the same issue

Comment: hello @davideghz, nope. i just did a small layout modification just for iOS to have all the area sortable without the link, and then the <a> link button outside. I hate this kind of exceptions but couldn't find a solution 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This css-style blocks the touch action you are referring to on iOS safari. At the time of question-asking i believe the default popup is the one shown in the picture. But now it navigates to the actual page in a small modal window, in addition to showing some options

```
a {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

Navigate to this on iOS for test: https://jsfiddle.net/hygf4Lrk/3/

It blocks both long-press (tap and hold for maybe 1s) and force-touch (press hard but instantly) wich result in the same action of link-preview by default.

Comment: Thanks this will help to solve this annoying behavior
Yes, that popup has changed in some current versions.